# Is it normal that is not rounding while parsing? NumberFormat

Tags: java, io, format, number-formatting

Why does it not round in the parsing process?

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
System.out.println(format.getMaximumFractionDigits());// 3
System.out.println(format.getRoundingMode());// half even
Double dob = (Double)format.parse("1212.35656");
System.out.println(dob);// output is 1212.35656
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digit counts are only used for formatting. When you parse a number you always get the number that best matches the input, even if it has more digits than the `NumberFormat` would use to format.

To parse a number from a string and then round to a given number of fractional digits you can use `BigDecimal` from the `java.math` package:

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal("1212.35656");
double dob = bd.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue();
```

Comment: for no particular reason though? design speaking

Comment: This part of the doc, in the parameter, seems to actually say that `Parameters:
newValue the maximum number of fraction digits to be shown; if less than zero, then zero is used. The concrete subclass may enforce an upper limit to this value appropriate to the numeric type being formatted.` Here, the `numeric type` seems to hint about being only for formatting. [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29)

Comment: I think the current behavior is reasonable: the alternatives would be silently degrading the precision of the numbers (= bad) or throwing an exception when the input has more digits than expected (= also bad)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain what you desire you need to call the formatter metod of the implementation NumberFormat loaded (in your case DecimalFromat); i just added the needed lines at the end and wrapped in a main:

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class NumberFormatRounding {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            System.out.println(formatter.getMaximumFractionDigits());// 3
            System.out.println(formatter.getRoundingMode());// half even
            Double dob = (Double) formatter.parse("1212.35656");
            System.out.println(dob);// output is 1212.35656
            String formattedDob = formatter.format(dob.doubleValue());
            System.out.println(formattedDob);// output is 1212.357
        }

    }
```

Note that the formattedDob is a String